# Yii2: Call to a member function saveAs() on null while uploading multiple file

Tags: php, yii2

While uploading multiple file getting this error:

When I put `[['file'], 'file', 'maxFiles' => 4],`in model getting following error:

```
Call to a member function saveAs() on null
```

But when I put this `[['file'], 'file'],` in model, its uploading.

Why am I getting error?

View:

```
<?php  echo $form->field($model,'file[]')->label(false)->widget(FileInput::classname(), 
                          [
                          'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*', 'multiple'=>true],
                          'pluginOptions'=>['allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png']
                          ]]);  
                      ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new RoomTypes();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            $imageName = $model->room_type;
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
            $model->file->saveAs( 'uploads/room_img/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
            //save the path in the db column
            $model->images = 'uploads/room_img/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: $model is null, are you creating the object properly on the controller?

Comment: i have updated the question.

Comment: print_r($model ) check it to debug

Answer (score 1):

Use [getInstances](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstances()-detail) instead of [getInstance](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstance()-detail) as according to their respective documentations, the first returns all uploaded files for a given model attribute while the second is designed to return a single one.
Then loop and save them one by one :

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) { 
     $imageName = $model->room_type;

     $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');

     $all_files_paths = [];

     foreach ($model->imageFiles as $file_instance) {
        // this should hold the new path to which your file will be saved
        $path = 'uploads/room_img/' . $file_instance->baseName . '.' . $file_instance->extension;

        // saveAs() method will simply copy the file 
        // from its temporary folder (C:\xampp\tmp\php29C.tmp) 
        // to the new one ($path) then will delete the Temp File
        $file_instance->saveAs($path);

        // here the file should already exist where specified within $path and 
        // deleted from C:\xampp\tmp\ just save $path content somewhere or in case you need $model to be
        // saved first to have a valid Primary Key to maybe use it to assign
        // related models then just hold the $path content in an array or equivalent :
        $all_files_pathes []= $path;
     }

     $model->save();

     /*
        after $model is saved there should be a valid $model->id or $model->primaryKey
        you can do here more stuffs like :

        foreach($all_files_pathes as $path) {
            $image = new Image();
            $image->room_id = $model->id;
            $image->path = $path;
            $image->save();
        }
     */

     return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
 }
```

See [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#uploading-multiple-files) for more info.

Comment: `Getting unknown property: backend\controllers\RoomTypesController::imageFiles` getting this error

Comment: I just updated. should be `$model->file` instead of `$this->file` as you are doing it inside controller and not inside model like in official docs. and `file` instead of `'imageFiles'`. my bad !

Comment: while saving `finfo_file(C:\xampp\tmp\php90FA.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ` getting this error

Comment: `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            $imageName = $model->room_type;
            $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');

            foreach ($model->imageFiles as $file_instance) 
            {
                 $file_instance->saveAs('uploads/room_img/' . $file_instance->baseName . '.' . $file_instance->extension);
 
                 $model->save();
            }
             
             return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
           
        }` 
here is the create action

Comment: hi again. why are u doing `$model->save()` inside the foreach loop ? `$model` is a single instance. `$model->imageFiles` is containing files instances through which we loop and we do `saveAs($path)` to each of them. and about the previous error it is normal as `tmp` folder will be cleaned after saving your file. I'll do an update

Comment: hi if I don't write `$model->save();` before `saveAs()` getiing this error `finfo_file(C:\xampp\tmp\php29C.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: yes it is normal. it is a `temporary` folder to hold the file until saved then cleaned up. that is how a php app should work. Sorry I have to go out now. i'll update my answer  when I came back. in like 30 or 45 min

Comment: sry for the delay but its still not working getting same error about `temp`

Comment: please read the commented lines in code. and the answer i left you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322316/yii2-finfo-filec-xampp-tmp-php29c-tmp-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-o/35325884#35325884). I spent time trying to help by giving a logical explanation on how it suppose to work and why it is throwing those errors. I never meant to provide a code that suppose to work with your case by simply doing a copy/past to it.